# Solve a prediction task using Tensor Flow

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, regression, prediction, data-analysis

I've been trying to solve a *prediction/regression* problem by using Tensor Flow, but i'm facing some problems. Let me give you some context before I explain my real problem.
The data I've been playing with  are a set of 5 features, let's call them **[f1, f2, f3, f4, f5]**, representing in somehow a particular phenomena identified by a real value (target).
What I've been trying to do is to train a *Multi Layer Perceptron* that learns the relationship among the features and the target values. In a nutshell i'd like to predict *real values* on the base of what the neural network as seen during the training phase. 
I've identified this problem as *prediction/regression* problem and wrote down the following code:

```
#picking device to run on
os.environ['CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES'] = '1'

# Parameters
learning_rate = 0.001
training_epochs = 99999
batch_size = 4096
STDDEV = 0.1

# Network Parameters
n_hidden_1 = 10 # 1st layer number of neurons
n_hidden_2 = 10 # 2nd layer number of neurons
n_hidden_3 = 10 # 3nd layer number of neurons
n_hidden_4 = 10 # 4nd layer number of neurons
n_hidden_5 = 10 # 5nd layer number of neurons

n_input = 5 # number of features
n_classes = 1 # one target value (float)

# tf Graph input
x = tf.placeholder("float", [None, n_input])
y = tf.placeholder("float", [None, n_classes])

# LOADING DATA
data_train = loader.loadDataset(dir_feat, train_path, 'TRAIN', features)
data_test = loader.loadDataset(dir_feat, test_path, 'TEST', features)

valid_period = 5
test_period = 10


def multilayer_perceptron(x, weights, biases):

    # Hidden layer with sigmoid activation
    layer_1 = tf.add(tf.matmul(x, weights['h1']), biases['b1'])
    layer_1 = tf.nn.sigmoid(layer_1)

    layer_2 = tf.add(tf.matmul(layer_1, weights['h2']), biases['b2'])
    layer_2 = tf.nn.sigmoid(layer_2)

    layer_3 = tf.add(tf.matmul(layer_2, weights['h3']), biases['b3'])
    layer_3= tf.nn.sigmoid(layer_3)

    layer_4 = tf.add(tf.matmul(layer_3, weights['h4']), biases['b4'])
    layer_4 = tf.nn.sigmoid(layer_4)

    layer_5 = tf.add(tf.matmul(layer_4, weights['h5']), biases['b5'])
    layer_5 = tf.nn.sigmoid(layer_5)

    # Output layer with linear activation
    out = tf.matmul(layer_5, weights['out']) + biases['out']

    return out


# Store layers weight & bias
weights = {
    'h1': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_input, n_hidden_1],stddev=STDDEV)),
    'h2': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden_1, n_hidden_2],stddev=STDDEV)),
    'h3': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden_2, n_hidden_3],stddev=STDDEV)),
    'h4': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden_3, n_hidden_4],stddev=STDDEV)),
    'h5': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden_4, n_hidden_5],stddev=STDDEV)),
    'out': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden_5, n_classes],stddev=STDDEV))


biases = {
    'b1': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden_1])),
    'b2': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden_2])),
    'b3': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden_3])),
    'b4': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden_4])),
    'b5': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden_5])),
    'out': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_classes]))
}

# Construct model
pred = multilayer_perceptron(x, weights, biases)

def RMSE():
    return tf.sqrt(tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(y - pred)))

cost = RMSE()
optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate=learning_rate).minimize(cost)

# Initializing the variables
init = tf.initialize_all_variables()

# Launch the graph
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)

    # Training cycle
    for epoch in range(1, training_epochs):
        avg_cost = 0.
        avg_R_square_train = []

        train_dataset = loader.Dataset(data=data_train, batch_size=batch_size, num_feats=n_input)

        total_batch = train_dataset.getNumberBatches()

        # Loop over all batches
        for i in range(total_batch):
            batch_x, batch_y = train_dataset.next_batch(update=True)
            # Run optimization op (backprop) and cost op (to get loss value)
            sess.run(optimizer, feed_dict={x: batch_x, y: batch_y})
            c_train = sess.run(cost, feed_dict={x: batch_x, y: batch_y})

            # Compute average loss
            avg_cost += c_train / total_batch

        print("Epoch:" + str(epoch) + ", TRAIN_loss = {:.9f}".format(avg_cost))

        # TESTING
        if epoch % test_period == 0:

            c_test = sess.run(cost, feed_dict={x: data_test[0][0], y: data_test[0][1]})

            print("Epoch:" + str(epoch) + ", TEST_loss = {:.9f}".format(c_test))
```

The problem I've encountered is that the *cost function* for the test set (after some iterations) got stuck in a local minima and doesn't decrease anymore.

```
Epoch:6697, TRAIN_loss = 2.162182076
Epoch:6698, TRAIN_loss = 2.156500859
Epoch:6699, TRAIN_loss = 2.157814605
Epoch:6700, TRAIN_loss = 2.160744122
Epoch:6700, TEST_loss = 2.301288128
Epoch:6701, TRAIN_loss = 2.139338647
...
Epoch:6709, TRAIN_loss = 2.166410744
Epoch:6710, TRAIN_loss = 2.162357884
Epoch:6710, TEST_loss = 2.301478863
Epoch:6711, TRAIN_loss = 2.143475396
...
Epoch:6719, TRAIN_loss = 2.145476401
Epoch:6720, TRAIN_loss = 2.150237552
Epoch:6720, TEST_loss = 2.301517725
Epoch:6721, TRAIN_loss = 2.151232243
...
Epoch:6729, TRAIN_loss = 2.163080522
Epoch:6730, TRAIN_loss = 2.160523321
Epoch:6730, TEST_loss = 2.301782370
...
Epoch:6739, TRAIN_loss = 2.156920952
Epoch:6740, TRAIN_loss = 2.162290675
Epoch:6740, TEST_loss = 2.301943779
...
```

I've tried to change the several hyper-parameters such as the number of hidden layer and/or the number of nodes, the learning rate, the batch size, etc but the situation doesn't change at all. I have also tried to use other loss function such as MAE, MSE.

Actually the number of data sample i have is roughly 270,000.

Can someone please suggest me how to solve this problem or give me some useful advices about it?

Thanks in advance.

Davide

Comment: What type of data you have ? Did you try with small subset of your dataset (5000 or 10000 samples) ?

Comment: @hars I have meteorology data features which should model real convective events and the may present an high variance. I've thought to use a small subset and it's the next things i'm going to do. Thank you